# Broken image link on company page hosted on cloudinary

Tags: support, bug, companies-page

The following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/users/story/lists/72325/appnovation-technologies?storyType=1) points to the company page with broken logo image.

Can the image be re-uploaded?